# Proving that $\frac{nx}{2+n+x}$ converges uniformly on $0 \le x \le 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Proving that $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{2+n+x}$ converges uniformly on $0 \le x \le 1$

Now I know I have to use the infinity metric, but I can't understand the solution given for this question.

The next step is $f_n(x)-x=-\frac{2x+x^2}{2+x+n}$ and that is then used to prove, yet I'm not sure as to why that route is taken for this question. I'd appreciate any hints or explanations.

Comment: Because $f(x) = x$ is the limit.

Comment: @T.Bongers thanks! got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|f_n(x)-x\right|=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\frac{2x+x^2}{2+x+n}\right|\leq \frac{3}{2+n} \to 0.
$$